# Entries inside controller

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

I'm trying to bring back a list of entries from a section. Currently I have the following:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'airports';
$criteria->airportcode = 'BCN';
$airportPrefHotels = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```

The airport section has a multiple entries field. I want to loop over them.

Is it possible?

Comment: What type of field is `airportcode`? Also, you tagged this with `craft3`, but I assume you're referring to Craft 2 here, correct?

Comment: It wouldn't let me add craft 2.

airportCode is a text field inside the section.

I want to access the entries inside the field attached to the airport section

Comment: So inside of an entry inside of a section with a handle of `airports`, you've got an [entries field] for relating other entries. What's the name of that field? And do you want to loop over all of those related entries for every parent entry?

Comment: I’m assuming there only one airport matching that criteria? If that’s right see my answer below @Christophfen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to query for the “airport” entry by using the `first()` method. `$airport->myEntriedFieldHandle` then returns an ElementCriteriaModel prepared to get all the entries selected in the Entries field.

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'airports';
$criteria->airportcode = 'BCN';
$airport = $criteria->first();

if ($airport) {
    $criteria = $airport->prefHotels;
    $airportPrefHotels = $criteria->find();

    if ($airportPrefHotels) {
        // do useful things with $airportPrefHotels
    }
}
```